# Can a Spring Bean programmatically replaced in an loaded SpringContext

Tags: spring, integration-testing, applicationcontext

I want write an integration test but with one minor restriction. I got a TimeSourceBean that I want to mock out. This TimeSourceBean is used several times deep in the application. (no way to do this with reflection)

Everything is done by autowire.

I think I could load in my test an additional XML with an implementation I like to have.
see: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943475/can-spring-framework-override-annotation-based-configuration-with-xml-based-conf/)!

But really nice would be when I can create my mock TimeSourceBean in the test itself and register it (replace the original bean) to the context

=> so before I start the test, I create the mock and register my bean like this:

context.registerBean(timeSourceBeanMockVersion);

Any ideas if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an other bean/class that implement the same interface (hopefully you use them), and mark this other bean class as @Primary.

But then you need to make sure that this primary bean is only loaded in the test cases you need them.