# How to override an imported resource using Spring @Configuration?

Tags: java, spring, configuration, dependency-injection

Is it possible to override imported resources using Spring annotation configuration?

**The configuration class:**

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource({"classpath:applicationContext.xml"})
public class CoreConfiguration {

    @Resource(name = "classA")
    private ClassA classA;

    @Bean(name = "nameIWantToOverride")
    private ClassB classB() {
       return new ClassB("different setting");
    }

}
```

**The applicationContext.xml includes:**

```
<bean name="classA" class="a.b.c.ClassA">
     <property name="nameIWantToOverride" ref="classB" />
</bean>
```

If classA has a classB field but I want it to use the ClassB I define in my configuration class, is that possible? I tried switching the order but that didn't help. It seems XML takes precedence as when I run a simple test of instantiating the config, it never reaches the classB method. If I change the name so it doesn't match the bean in the xml file, then it does reach the classB method.

I've seen where it can work the other way: [Can spring framework override Annotation-based configuration with XML-based configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943475/can-spring-framework-override-annotation-based-configuration-with-xml-based-conf) but what about this direction? Since this is the newer way of doing things, I would think it you'd be able to do this.

What can I do to resolve this?

Edit: Updated with XML. Assume classA has multiple fields but I just want to replace the one.

Comment: I can't really tell what you're asking.  Please elaborate, perhaps with some code.

Comment: @skaffman I updated it. I want to override xml spring config with annotation config. Is Sudhakar correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot override spring xml configuration using annotation.

Spring XML configuration always takes precedence to  annotation configuration

Comment: That stinks :( I guess I'll just have to create an xml file with my overriden bean.

Comment: Vanilla Java 1-0 Spring